# abortBroadcast() in which sdk version does not work?

Tags: android

abortBroadcast order to prevent messages from reaching the inbox is used, in which SDK version does not work?
 I know it work form sdk<18 and not workin for skd 19.
my qution is: it working for sdk 18 and >=20?

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? It can work up through API Level 18. It will definitely not work starting with 19.

Comment: It can work in 18. It will not work in >=19.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question very well, but I checked the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#abortBroadcast%28%29) and it does not say anything about not working from a particular SDK. What it does say is the following:

> Sets the flag indicating that this receiver should abort the current
>   broadcast; only works with broadcasts sent through
>   Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. This will prevent any other broadcast
>   receivers from receiving the broadcast. It will still call
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) of the BroadcastReceiver that the caller of
>   Context.sendOrderedBroadcast passed in.
>
> **This method does not work with non-ordered broadcasts such as those
>   sent with Context.sendBroadcast**